# com.***.**.**.security.CustomUserDetail cannot be cast to com.***.**.**.security.CustomUserDetail

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-security

When class casting `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User` to `com.***.**.config.security.CustomUserDetail` while fetching AuthenticatedUser I got exception as `"java.lang.ClassCastException"`.

Error message was `com.***.**.config.security.CustomUserDetail cannot be cast to com.***.**.config.security.CustomUserDetail`.

Source Code :

```
public static CustomUserDetail getAuthenticatedUser() {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (auth == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Authentication Required.");
        }
        Object principal = auth.getPrincipal();
        User user = (User) principal;
        return (CustomUserDetail) user;
    }
```

Error occurred at return statement while mapping `user` to `CustomUserDetail`

**CustomUserDetail Class**

```
import java.util.Collection;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import com.***.**.globaluser.domain.GlobalUser;

public class CustomUserDetail extends org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private GlobalUser globalUser;

    public CustomUserDetail(GlobalUser user,
            Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        super(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), authorities);
        this.globalUser = user;
    }

    public CustomUserDetail(GlobalUser user, boolean enabled,
            boolean accountNonExpired, boolean credentialsNonExpired,
            boolean accountNonLocked,
            Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        super(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), enabled, accountNonExpired,
                credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, authorities);
        this.globalUser = user;
    }

    public GlobalUser getUserLogin() {
        return globalUser;
    }

}
```

Comment: Sounds like a classloader problem. Where do you run the code?

Comment: It's a Spring Boot project. I run it as a Java Application.

Comment: Is class 'User' derived from 'CustomUserDetail'?
the principal object is 'Object' type and you can directly cast it to 'CustomUserDetail'.

Comment: Class User is org.springframework.security.core.userdetails and CustomUserDetail extends org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User.

Comment: I did that too but same error.

Comment: I guess you are just storing the User instance in your custom class. If that is the only implementation I would suggest directly use the User instance returned by the principal. yeah, I am not answering the actual problem.
public static User getAuthenticatedUser() {
....

User user = (User) principal;
return user;
}